# How to make Stata wait for user input in each loop iteration?

Tags: stata

I have a situation where users need to review/edit data by hand. I want to show them chunks of data at a time. I am doing this using a loop. My problem is to make the loop wait of the user to say that she's done with one chunk before moving to the next chunk.

I've tried `set more on`, `pause on`, and `_request`, but no luck. Here's an example of my set up with some fake data:

```
clear

set obs 100
gen id   = int( 5*uniform() )
gen var1 = uniform()

levelsof id, local(ids)
foreach id of local ids {

    edit if id == `id'
    
    /* 
       pause, 
       wait for user to hit any key in 
       the Command Window before moving
       to the next iteration
    */ 

}
```

Comment: Haven't done anything similar in an age, but see the help for `display _request()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Nick Cox's comment, here's my solution.

```
clear

set obs 100
gen id   = int( 5*uniform() )
gen var1 = uniform()

levelsof id, local(ids)
foreach id of local ids {

    edit if id == `id'
    
    * user must type _next_ in Command Window for next iteration
    local cmd 0
    while ("`cmd'" != "next") {
        
        display _request(cmd)
        local cmd "$cmd"
        
        /* here's the trick: the edits (replace var1 = bla in bla)
           are captured by _request(). I need to send the replace
           command back to stata */
        if ("`cmd'" != "next") {
            `cmd'
        }
    }
}
```